# how to send multiple random messages on telegram

Tags: php, telegram

I use this php script to send a message into a telegram channel

```
<?php
$botToken = "yourbottoken";
$chat_id = "@yourchannel";
$message = "your message";
$bot_url    = "https://api.telegram.org/bot$botToken/";
$url = $bot_url."sendMessage?chat_id=".$chat_id."&text=".urlencode($message);
file_get_contents($url);
?>
```

My problem is this:

I would to create 5 messages

message 1
message 2
message 3
message 4
message 5

how can I modify the script so that, when cronjob starts, script print a random message (only a message for a cronjob)?

thanks

Comment: Just call the script five times? What have you tired to solve it yourself? We're glad to help you sort out issues, but you need to show us that you've at least made an effort trying to solve it yourself first. Please copy/paste your code (including any attempt) into the question instead of just linking to it (since that's not _your_ code and if that post gets deleted, the question wont make sense for future visitors).

Comment: I know, I would learn a better solution ;)

Comment: Not sure what "better solution" you're expecting to find? The code is pretty minimal as it is. If you want to send five different messages, you need to call the API five times with different messages. Again, what have you tried and exactly where are you stuck?

Comment: I know I could use 5 script and call it with 5 cronjob, but I thanked to use an array of 5 messages

Comment: So put this code in a function that takes the message as an argument and then get 5 random messages from an array and call the function 5 times in a loop? Have you actually tried anything? We're here to help you fix _specific issues_ you might run into with your code, but we're not here to just rewrite it for you (which an answer to this would require us to).

Answer (score 0):

Create a function, Call the function multiple times.
But don't exceed 30 request per second, Or your bot will get flood error

```php
<?php
$botToken = 'bot_token';
$chat_id = '@yourchannel';
$message = 'your message';
$bot_url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot$botToken/";

function sendMessage($chat_id, string $text) {
    return file_get_contents($bot_url."sendMessage?chat_id=$chat_id&text=$text");
}

# You can send whatever messages you want
sendMessage($chat_id, 'message 1');
sendMessage($chat_id, 'message 2');
sendMessage($chat_id, 'message 3');
sendMessage($chat_id, 'message 4');
sendMessage($chat_id, 'message 5');
?>
```